# Can't link against libsqlite3.a to create my own static library

Tags: sqlite, g++, linker-errors

I'm creating a static library that contains some objects including one that depends on sqlite3. This is my make file; it basically compiled the 3 cpp files into objects, put them into a .a lib and then use this library to get my main binary

```
CPPSRCS := \
$(LIBDIR)/database/active_database.$(SRCEXT) \
$(LIBDIR)/sd_card/sd_card.$(SRCEXT) \
$(LIBDIR)/led/led.$(SRCEXT) 

OBJS := $(CPPSRCS:.cpp=.o)

lib/%.o: %.$(SRCEXT)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -lsqlite3

lib_$(APP).a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) rcs lib_$(APP).a $(OBJS)

$(APP): lib_$(APP).a 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/$@.$(SRCEXT) -o $(DESTDIR)/$@ lib_$(APP).a
```

My static library is built but when trying to get my binary against it I get undefined reference:

```
lib_XX.a(active_database.o): In function `database::ActiveDatabase::sqlite_exec_wrapper(std::string, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*)':
database/active_database.cpp:174: undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
database/active_database.cpp:178: undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
lib_XX.a(active_database.o): In function `database::ActiveDatabase::init_db()':
```

I can see that -lsqlite3 (in /usr/lib) is not included in the compilation but I can't seem to force it to be included when I build my static library.

Comment: You need to include `-lsqlite3` when linking APP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-lsqlite3` is ignored when compiling into object files because no linking happens.

You have three options.

- You can add the SQLite object files to your static library `lib_XX.a`.
- You can perform a relocatable link and produce a single `.o` file which contains the entire static library *and* SQLite, using `ld -r`.
- Or consumers of your library need to link to your library *and* SQLite, using `-l_XX -lsqlite3`.

The last option is the most common approach and can be automated somewhat with tools like `pkg-config`.

Comment: I ended up using your 3rd approach & it worked perfectly fine.